# font-face on android 4.0.x doesn't work

Tags: android, css, font-face

I'm building a mobile Application with JQM and I need to declare own Fonts with font-face.

I'm including the font **css** file `fonts.css` as the first loaded css file in my index.html and declared the `font-faces` like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"MyFont";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    src:url("fonts/MyFont.woff");
    src:url("fonts/MyFont.eot?") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/MyFont.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/MyFont.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/MyFont.svg#MyFont") format("svg");
}
```

My two Test devices are the `Google Nexus 7` with **Android 4.2.1** and a `Motorola Razr` with **Android  4.0.4**.

On Google Nexus, it works both on mobile Chrome and with PhoneGap. But on the Motorola Razr, it works only with mobile Chrome. Both the stock Android Browser and Phonegap don't use `MyFont`.

Is there any Workaround to get the my Font work on Android 4.0.x?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a Samsung Galaxy SII Skyrocket with CM10. On 4.0.x, the OS browser was displaying `@font-face` fine. However, 4.2.1 was released today and when I updated it, `@font-face` does not load anymore.

Comment: Same problem for the stock browser and phonegap (which uses a webview) on Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.1 Jelly Beans. Note that the problem is not there with Chrome app. This is very annoying as the default Android font does not contains some glyphs and display blanks!

Answer (score 10):

Interesting. I'm having the reverse experience.

I have a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.1 (CM 10.1), that was loading fonts absolutely fine until the upgrade, but has started getting really weird with the CSS since the update (only in the native WebKit, not Chrome, which still works).

I realized it was not the font-face issue, but that the CSS specificity is getting screwed up (using bootstrap as a base, and then replacing with my own CSS). Even inline styles don't show up if bootstrap included, everything works fine if bootstrap removed. Very strange.

As for your reverse of my issue, a couple of thoughts:

- Why the first src with a .woff? I've seen it with a .eot for IE backwards compatibility mode, but browsers using .woff should be able to use it from the second src. Maybe try removing the first src? (This shouldn't be the issue, as WebKit should overwrite with second src)
- How are you loading the font files? From local storage? From a web server? I know with Firefox if the server with the font files is different from the files with the type, it won't load without an Allow Origin header.
- Do you need to load this same font definition in other non-webkit browsers? If not, consider removing all the files except the .woff.
- Are you sure the issue is the font-face? Try setting the font declaration to a non-default system font (such as 'serif'). See if the font declaration is being applied, or could it be that your font-face is fine, but the css is somehow not applying the font to the type? (As has been my case this past week)

It's a bit hard to know without additional information. Your @font-face declaration, other than the weirdness of the first src being a .woff, seems like it should work fine. My guess is the issue lies elsewhere, not with that code fragment.

**Edit:**

I tracked down my issue --- on Android 4.2.1 the CSS option `text-rendering:` was behaving quite differently from Chrome and previous Android versions. If you are using this option, see if changing or removing it fixes the issue for you. It's the only thing I can think of that I've seen as being different in how Android 4.0 vs Android 4.2 webkit has been rendering fonts.

Comment: `Why the first src with a .woff?` I copied the fonts.css from our website where other people build it to the mobile app directory. But you are right, use the eot file as the first src would be better.

`How are you loading the font files?` for tests the font Files are stored on a webserver and the app is used through a webbrowser. Build with phonegap the fonts are storage on the device under `/assets/styles/fonts/`
- I only need to load the font on that App.
- I changed the font-family in the style.css to 'Verdana' and the font is changing.

- text-rendering is nowhere used.

Comment: Not only does `text-rendering` need to be turned off, also `-webkit-font-smoothing`

Comment: `text-rendering` off worded for me, after five hours headbanging. thanks

Comment: `text-rendering: auto` fixed my problem too. Thank you for posting this edit. A lot of time wasted trying to fix this.

Comment: I am testing with a website instead of a phonegap app to track down the issue, even after deactivating `text-rendering` and `-webkit-font-smoothing` I still face the problem (Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.2.1 Jelly Beans with stock browser).

Comment: I have the problem even with `text-rendreing:auto` Android 4.1