# Custom Persian And Arabic Fonts in Android 4.1.2 Phonegap (Cordova) not working

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, font-face, persian

I tried to make custom fonts for my application in phonegap. For that, I wrote this code in my html file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'customfont';
src: url('fonts/BMitra.eot?#') format('eot'), 
url('fonts/BMitra.woff') format('woff'), 
url('fonts/BMitra.ttf') format('truetype'); 
font-style: normal;
}
    body {
        font-family: "customfont";
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

....

```
<body>
    <h>Custom Fonts</h>
    <div style="font-family: 'customfont';" id='txt1'>This is for sample</div>
</body>
```

It works fine on Ripple (chrome emulator) but it doesn't work on the Device (Samsung Android 4.1.2)

I have `googled` and `stack-overflowed` to find the solution, i found this post [font-face on android 4.0.x doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990423/font-face-on-android-4-0-x-doesnt-work) which says to have `text-rendreing:auto` but it didn't work too.

Any help, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally I overcome this issue on Persian And Arabic custom fonts,

Keep all the codes with `@fontface` as same as it is,
Download this package http://averta.net/labs/fa/?p=10

From extracted archive, add `bifon-1.1b.js` to your html and use this script

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    $('#txt1').text(FarsiStyle.convert('سلام عليكم').split('').reverse().join('').split(' ').reverse().join(' '));

}
```

which txt1 is a div or span.

p.s Thanks to Mr. Morteza F. Shojaei

Comment: Thanx, That's the solution. but your link is not valid.
this is the new link : 
http://averta.net/labs/fa/?p=10